# Java: Int Array, measure the length of the array element

Tags: java, arrays

In Java.  Let's say you're given the following Array. Or something similar

```
int[] anArray = {10, 20, 30, 40, 1000};
```

Is there a way to take the length of the array **element** at anArray[4]; ?

I need to know if the array[x] is == 4. As in 2004, or 1000, or 1968.

How can i do this?

Comment: What do you mean by length of an array element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert the element to a string and get the length of the string, or if its integers you can test if it's between 1000 and 9999.

Answer (score 3):

Convert your array object to string and check is length :

```
anArray[x].toString().length
```

Comment: I doubt that the compiler is going to like this. You can't dereference an int and this isn't a case where autoboxing is going to be used.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the element to a string and then find the length of the string.

You could also use repeated division by 10 in a while loop to find your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (Integer.toString(anArray[x]).length() == 4) {
    // it's 4 long
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly geekier approach:

```
int lengthOfElement4 = (int) Math.floor((Math.log(anArray[4]) / Math.log(10) + 1);
```

@Mark's second option will probably be quicker though...